# Period matrices of isogenous abelian varieties

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

It is well-known that two principally polarized abelian varieties of dimension $g$ over $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic to each other if and only if their period matrices lie in the same $\text{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit. Do we know anything about how period matrices of isogenous abelian varieties are related to each other?

Comment: I meant see [Milne's book](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/av.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I think you're referring to a previous comment you wrote, but I don't think I can see it. Are you referring to something from a particular part of Milne's book? I can't find a specific reference to period matrices in the section in Chapter 1 on isogenies except some mention of "period vectors", so I think I'm missing something.